# Can we use any other unique constraint as primary key in database like a phone number, or national Id

Tags: mysql, database

I'm creating a database that has column of person's mobile phone number. Now i just want to know without making a separate column for id and making it a primary key, can i make this column a primary key for this table?

Comment: You probably could.  But I highly recommend having a synthetic, auto-incremented primary key.

Comment: What advantage will you get in defining a column as primary key that would not be used for search purposes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted above, you technically could use a phone number as a primary key, but it is not a best practice, because:

1. You would not be able to insert another user who happens to have the same phone number (primary keys must be unique).
2. You will run into what is known as an "update anomaly", if you have other tables that reference your tables primary key, and you decide to change a user's mobile number, you will have to also update the mobile number in all of the dependent tables.[How to maintain referential integrity](http://www.dummies.com/programming/sql/how-to-maintain-referential-integrity-in-a-multitable-sql-database/)
3. From a performance standpoint, indexes on numeric values are usually more efficient than indexes on varchars, and will improve the performance on your joins, and the index will take up less space.

More often than not, your best bet is to use an auto-incrementing surrogate key.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can define any column as primary key. The question is if such definition is good or bad. If you are going to use a phone number (that should be stored as string) and the column will not only be a primary key but also unique, and you will make sure that no attempt will be made to insert two times the same number for different people, then it should be OK.